TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object at Function.use
I checking some code on NodeJS but here is the error I am getting and notable to resolve it.

  throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn))
  ^

TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a
Object
at Function.use (D:\React\feedback-app\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:469:13)
at Function. (D:\React\feedback-app\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:227:21)
at Array.forEach ()
at Function.use (D:\React\feedback-app\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:224:7)
at Object. (D:\React\feedback-app\server.js:27:5)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1378:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1437:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1212:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:142:12)
Node.js v21.6.2

Here is my auth.js
const express = require('express');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const User = require('../models/User');

const router = express.Router();

// Register a new user
router.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
    const { username, email, password } = req.body;

    try {
        // Check if the user already exists
        let user = await User.findOne({ email });
        if (user) {
            return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'User already exists' });
        }

        // Create a new user
        user = new User({ username, email, password });

        // Hash the password before saving the user
        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
        user.password = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

        await user.save();

        // Create and return JWT token
        const payload = { user: { id: user.id } };
        jwt.sign(payload, process.env.JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: '1h' }, (err, token) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            res.json({ token });
        });

    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        res.status(500).send('Server error');
    }
});

// Login a user
router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    try {
        // Check if the user exists
        let user = await User.findOne({ email });
        if (!user) {
            return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Invalid credentials' });
        }

        // Compare the entered password with the hashed password
        const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
        if (!isMatch) {
            return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Invalid credentials' });
        }

        // Create and return JWT token
        const payload = { user: { id: user.id } };
        jwt.sign(payload, process.env.JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: '1h' }, (err, token) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            res.json({ token });
        });

    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        res.status(500).send('Server error');
    }
});

module.exports = router;

This is my server.js
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());//middleware

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI,{
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
}).then(() => {
    console.log('Connected to MongoDB');
}).catch(err => {
    console.error('Error connecting to MongoDB:', err.message);
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Welcome to the Feedback App!');
});

const authRoutes = require('./routes/auth');
console.log("test");
console.log(authRoutes);
console.log("test");
// Routes
app.use('/api/auth', authRoutes); // Add the auth routes



const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});


console.log(authRoutes); ... is that a function or an object?

it is object!!!

well ... the error is correct

yeah but why is that and its solution?

is it app.use('/api/auth', authRoutes); // Add the auth routes that causes the error? Seems odd if it is

Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. You won't be able to reproduce it with the code you provided. If you're unsure, make an isolated example on your side and check if it works. No .use() in use can cause this error. If you're unsure what is authRoutes or anything else you provide to .use(), debug a value

I have my whole repo https://github.com/MuhammadFaizanKhan/feedback-app

@MuhammadFaizanKhan Consider using @ in order for other users to receive notifications. It's not reproducible. Add the missing dependencies, and you'll be able to run it

@MuhammadFaizanKhan I can't reproduce. With the given repo, after I installed the missing requirements not listed in package.json and fixed the typo in the require statement (from ../models/User' to ../model/User), the app comes up.
